# Identity Hash failure when getting keyId

Tags: namedcredentials

I'm receiving this error below, but it starts coincidentally after applying the update `Summer'21`.

> IdentityHash failure when getting keyId: 02G1H0000005AOD of type CREDENTIAL for Context Org: 00D0t0000001U1H .This is not expected. This may indicate that the Context org is accessing another's encryption keys (which is very bad).

Someone already had this error or knows how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you include the code that results in this error? Based on the verbiage of the error (`This may indicate that the Context org is accessing another's encryption keys`), this sounds like a potentially terrible bug from the Salesforce side.

Comment: Open a support case, "this is not expected" is quite right.